# What does "Service exited with abnormal code: 1" mean?

Tags: macos, launchd

I'm looking to see if a LaunchDaemon script is running at its assigned time. Looking at that time in the Console produces this result:

"mac-hostname com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (com.user.delprofiles[48049]): Service exited with abnormal code:1"

The script is meant to remove all user profiles save a select few every night. It appears as if it is working as there are no unwanted profiles on the HDD. Just not sure what "abnormal code:1" means.

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you run a program (such as your script that deletes user profiles) - it will leave behind an exit status code when done executing.

The exit status code is 0 when everything has gone according to plan. Anything other than 0 is an "abnormal code", usually indicating some kind of error or warning.

The exit status code 1 is just a "generic error" - it could mean anything. You'll have to look into the script you have to see which exit status codes it uses, and what the causes of them are.

Comment: Thanks. There's no error handling written into the script.

Comment: If nothing else is specified, the exit status code of a script is usually the exit status code of the last executed command in that script. It all depends ofcourse on what kind of script you have (i.e. is it bash-scripts, Ruby script, AppleScript, or whatever).